# Opening multiple files for reading/writing in Python using "with open", without enumerating and listing each one exclusively?

Tags: python, file, io, filewriter

What I **know** how to do:

`with open("file1.txt","w") as file1, open("file2.txt","w") as file2, open("file3.txt","w") as file3, open("file4.txt","w") as file4:`

What I **want** to approximately do:

`with open([list of filenames],"w") as [list of file variable names]:`

Any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`contextlib.ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack) as container for file handlers. It will close all opened files automatically.

Example:

```
filenames = "file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt", "file4.txt"
with ExitStack() as fs:
    file1, file2, file3, file4 = (fs.enter_context(open(fn, "w")) for fn in filenames)
    ...
    file2.write("Some text")
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll check this out and fiddle with it some and see what I can get and get back to you.

Comment: @Alexander, if you want to work with variables instead of dict, you can use `file1, file2, file3, file4 = (file_stack.enter_context(open(fn, "w")) for fn in filenames)`

Comment: yeah, I think that's more suting to my needs. Thanks!

Comment: Did ! Thanks you, it worked. One thing, though: I used ```filenames = ( "file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt", "file4.txt" )``` . Note that this differs from your suggested first line in that there are parentheses around the enumeration of filenames. Dunno if it would have worked without them. It probably would have, but I added them just in case!

Comment: @Alexander, with or without parentheses it will create *tuple*.